# Why is there no inversion in "Who do you think you are"?

Tags: subject-verb-inversion

Look at these 2 sentences

1. Who do you think is the richest man ?
2. Who do you think you are ?

Try omit "do you think" and we can see the conflict. Because people often ask "Who are you".
But with "do you think", it has no inversion

I see they are the same structure, but why is there no inversion (subject and verb) in the second sentence ?

Comment: Your premise is wrong. These do not have the same structure. In the first one, *who* is the subject. In the second one, *who* is the object. To have the first structure in the second case, you would have to ask, "Who do you think is you?", and you would still have the inversion.

Comment: @RegDwighт I've already known about that. But my question is different. Try omit "do you think" and you can see the conflict. Also, "Who do you think is you", I think "you" must come with "are" ?

Comment: Obviously you do not understand. You just repeated your question all over again. I will have to repeat myself, then. In the first question, *who* is the subject, and *the richest man* is the object. Who is the richest man. In the second question, *you* is the subject, and *who* is the object. You are who. Not, who is you, in which case you'd have the inversion right back.